# How do I get a list of servers and their public DNS with Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a group of EC2 instances in a security group.  I am looking for a way to obtain a list of their public DNS address's from command line.  I have a script that uses RSYNC to make sure a set of files is updated across these servers.  They are in an elastic load balancer and the amount of servers in the group changes enough that I do not want to have to maintain the list by hand.  I want to avoid using AWK or SED to pull information out of ec2-describes-instances, I'd prefer to use the API directly.  Anybody have any great suggestions? :)

Comment: Why not put a cronjob on the instances themselves to pull down whatever files they need? Thats going to be a lot more stable than relying on one box to push updates to many. You could also use a user data script to pull in the files at boot time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incase anybody is searching for a solution, I ended up using Amazon's PHP SDK.  It allows you to filter results by many different criteria.  I simply did a describe instance request, filtering by a specific security group (where security-group-name is the one you want to search for!)

```
 // Get the response from a call to the DescribeInstances operation.
 $response = $ec2->describe_instances(array('Filter' => array(array('Name' => 'group-name
', 'Value' => 'security-group-name'))));
```

Comment: If this solved your question, please mark it as such.

Answer (score 5):

The command line output format is pretty static, and you can control when it might changed because the toolkit is your hands. I keep a copy of the api tools in a versioned repository along with whatever software I've written that uses it, this way they always work together at a given version.

If you do decide to go this way, here is a simple grab to get the public DNS address of everything running. Obviously you could request this for a specific group too.

```
ec2-describe-instances | grep 'INSTANCE' | cut  -f 4
```

Comment: This doesn't really work because I want to grab only instances from a particular security group.  It splits this information onto separate lines.

Answer (score -1):

```
ec2din -F instance-state-name=running | grep -e TAG -e INSTANCE | sed -e 's/TAG//' | awk '{print $4}'
```

You can also add filters for your desired security group adding -F group-name=your-group

Comment: Is there an important difference between your answer and [Caleb's](http://serverfault.com/a/264041/26130)?  They look remarkably similar.  If there is, you should probably edit your answer to describe why yours is better.